# jquery $.post not working on google marker drag event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a draggable marker in my map. I created this draggable map inside draggableMarker() function. When I drag this marker, it will make a jquery post to check if the marker is in the database. If available then the this marker must go back to its original position. Here what I did is if marker is in the database then setMap(null) and again call the draggableMarker() function which is working fine but when I again try to drag this marker this jquery post is not working.

This is what I have tried in my code.

```
function initialize() {
    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-single'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: parseFloat($('#mun_lat').val()), lng: parseFloat($('#mun_lon').val())},
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    });
draggableMarker();

function draggableMarker(){
    current = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: myMap,
        draggable: true,
        icon: com,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: {lat: parseFloat($('#lat').val()), lng: parseFloat($('#lat2').val())},
    });
}

google.maps.event.addListener(current,'dragend',function(event)
{
    $('#curs1').val(current.position.lng());
    $('#curs2').val(current.position.lat());
    $.post("checkAvailable.php",
    {
        lon: current.position.lng(),
        lat: current.position.lat()
    },
    function(data){
        current.setMap(null);
        draggableMarker();
    }
}, 'json');
});
```

}

Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign your Google event in an function like this:

```
function assignedEvent(){

    google.maps.event.addListener(current,'dragend',function(event)
    {
        $('#curs1').val(current.position.lng());
        $('#curs2').val(current.position.lat());`enter code here`
        $.post("checkAvailable.php",
        {
            lon: current.position.lng(),
            lat: current.position.lat()
        },
        function(data){
            current.setMap(null);
            draggableMarker();
        }
    }, 'json');
    });
    }
```

When you receive the Ajax response, the event is no longer taken into account on your new map marker. You will have to re-assign it like this

```
function assignedEvent(){
    google.maps.event.addListener(current,'dragend',function(event) {
        $('#curs1').val(current.position.lng());
        $('#curs2').val(current.position.lat());
        $.post("checkAvailable.php", {
            lon: current.position.lng(),
            lat: current.position.lat()
        }, function(data) {
            current.setMap(null);
            draggableMarker();
            assignedEvent()//Here you assign the event to the marker again
        }
        }, 'json');
    });
}
```

Comment: If I cant assign the google event inside a function then which solution you propose @Patrik Ken

Comment: You will have to copy all of your code that assigns the Google event to Ajax response function in order to assign the event again to the new marker

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(current,'dragend',function(event) {
    $('#curs1').val(current.position.lng());
    $('#curs2').val(current.position.lat());
    $.post("checkAvailable.php", {
        lon: current.position.lng(),
        lat: current.position.lat()
    }, function(data) {
        current.setMap(null);
        draggableMarker();
            google.maps.event.addListener(current,'dragend',function(event) {
    $('#curs1').val(current.position.lng());
    $('#curs2').val(current.position.lat());
    $.post("checkAvailable.php", {
        lon: current.position.lng(),
        lat: current.position.lat()
    }, function(data) {
        current.setMap(null);
        draggableMarker();
    }
    }, 'json');
});
    }
    }, 'json');
});
```